# how to fetch range of values using LIKE operator in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like

I my DB i want to select data which having A15-A19 using LIKE operator but couldnt get required result.
the code i made as `SELECT * FROM MASTER_RULE WHERE VALUE BETWEEN LIKE 'A15%' AND 'A19%'` and also tried regular expression as `SELECT * FROM MASTER_RULE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(value, 'A[1-9]')` . But regexp gives all records not specified range 15-19.

How to achieve the solution for this?

Comment: Can you give us the example of the data in your column ? Are they only like A15, A16, A07... ?

Comment: Data present as A15,A16,...A50.

Comment: Also your first query is not ok, it is throwing an error.

Comment: Please show sample data and the desired results. Should a value such as `A15xyz` match the criteria?

Comment: And what about `A153`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is not ok, it has one extra keyword that you do not need.

Here is the regexp_like solution:

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER_RULE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(value, '^A[1][5-9]')
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5997235704fe50b82c8ee62a31f49711)

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the "BETWEEN SOLUTION":

```
SELECT * 
FROM MASTER_RULE 
WHERE substr(value, 2,length(value)-1) between 15 AND 19
```

Comment: REGP_EXP gives exact result but both BETWEEN operator query not gives required result.Anyhow thanks buddy@VBoka

Comment: @Nvr you are welcome. Happy to help. Please can you please give me more details why does the between not working ? What data does it return ?

Comment: `BETWEEN` doesn't do pattern matching, you shouldn't have `%` in the strings.

Comment: The regex should have `^` at the beginning to anchor it. Otherwise it will match `blahA15`

Comment: @Barmar I agree, I will remove my first two query's

Comment: Hi @Barmar I will also add the `^` - you are correct. Also, there should be some more modifications to my `REGEXP_LIKE` query because in this way it will also reutrn `A161`... Also my `BETWEEN` query will return error with examples like `blahA15`

Comment: Isn't that what he wants? His original question used a pattern, so I think he wants anything beginning with `A15` through `A19`/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217777/discussion-between-vboka-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use regular string comparisons:

```
where value >= 'A15' and
      value < 'A20'
```

Not only is this simple, but the code can also take advantage of an index on `value`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comments your data is like A15, A16, A17. etc you can achive your requirement with simple in clause also.

```
SELECT * FROM MASTER_RULE WHERE VALUE in ('A15','A16','A17','A18,'A19');
```